# How can i run a loop using ng-repeat 1 times more than data in array in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

> How can I run a loop in AngularJS one times more than it should run by default as per the data in array/json.

```
<div ng-repeat="quizqs in Quizdata.questions">
    <li ng-click="form.goTo(Form, {{$index + 1}})">
        <a href ng-class="{'selected' : currentStep >= {{$index + 1}}, 'done' : currentStep > {{$index + 1}}}">
            <div class="stepNumber">
                {{$index + 1}}
            </div>
            <span class="stepDesc text-small">Question No {{quizqs.id}} - {{Quizdata_Lenght}} -  {{$index + 1}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: what would be the data in that one extra iteration?

Comment: Push another object into the array in the controller.

Comment: can i ask you what is your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be try like this just push one object in to the array

https://plnkr.co/edit/LTxT2DEeAC0nVrmPEYLE?p=preview

**JS**

```
 $scope.data =[
{"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
{"Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
{"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
{"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"}]

var obj ={};
obj.name ="";
obj.London ="";

$scope.data.push(obj)
```